# Is there a way to hash my IP field in logfile in Apache Server?

Tags: apache-2.4

I have an Apache server. And i want to hash or remove the IP field in logfile when traffic come. 
Is there a better way than write a script to remove the IP field in every line,Or any apache module to hash the IP field ?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Pardon me if I read too much in your question, but please note that GDPR regulations do not forbid you to log ip-addresses, nor are you required to request permission in advance.  Logging ip-addresses *for purpose of security* is industry standard and for that specific reason allowed under articles of the GDPR article 6, § c, d and e

Comment: @HBruijn I know about the GDPR. But the customer ask to hash the IP address. Removing IP field is the 2nd option. I know there is a module to hash the IP field out there but i don't know the name. 
Btw, thanks for your kindness

Comment: Hashing IPv4 addresses is pointless, as the search space is too small to prevent brute-force reversing.

Comment: @womble Customer don't know about that. Anyway, they just want to hide it.

Comment: It is your job, as a professional, to educate your customer.  If they want to hide IPs from the logs, then just remove it from the `LogFormat` directive.

Comment: @womble i suggest to remove it already. But they don't want to do it, just want to hide it. And my job is also to satisfied the customer, LOL :D

Comment: *"The customer is always right"* is incorrect. - Even large enterprise customers can make requests that should be (strongly) discouraged and rejected because of valid practical, technical and legal concerns. - But please note that you can use a pipe `|` to stream log messages to an external program instead of directly to a file. That external program can then do all the pre-processing that needs to be done (such as hashing ip-addresses) before writing the resulting log to disk 
 See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#piped

Comment: @HBruijn I know, but the request of customers isn't valid, or technical or legal, it's just about the thing that i don't know how to do it. Btw, thanks for your comment. I will check it immediately

Comment: @AshBlake The consensus among bureaucrats I know of is that the IP address is in general personally identifiable information, and since it isn't strictly necessary for the operations under 6.1.c,d,e, the user should be informed. Regardless, if the customer wants true anonymity, and to prevent the possibility from certain web activity being traced back to specific users, logging IPs is problematic. Hashing them with a daily salt allows that anonymity to be retained while allowing admins to trace activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to customize the Apache log format as described in the [Log Files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) documentation.

> The server access log records all requests processed by the server.
>   The location and content of the access log are controlled by the
>   [`CustomLog`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directive. The [`LogFormat`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) directive can be used to simplify
>   the selection of the contents of the logs. This section describes how
>   to configure the server to record information in the access log.

From the [Custom Log Formats](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) list you can find that `%h` refers to:

> Remote hostname. Will log the IP address if `HostnameLookups` is set to
>   `Off`, which is the default.

By using a `LogFormat` without the `%h` you would stop logging the IP addresses, e.g.

```
LogFormat "%l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog logs/access_log common
```

Comment: Great. you make my day. I'm trying to read the module mod_rewrite all days. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Btw, do you know any module that can hash the IP field in logfile in Apache?

Comment: It looks like this isn't really the answer to the question you asked. I'm not interested in piping output of logs for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can log the hashed IP address in Apache 2.4. The solution I provide here allows you to log the IP address and Cookie in your CustomLog format, while allowing it to be logged for troubleshooting or for problematic IPs. Note, This does not prevent other modules such as mod_security, mod_status, PHP, or the application from also logging these.

My CustomLog is a tab-delimited format, useful for parsing with awk or splunk-forwarders. My solution is meant for an Apache server with reverse-proxies and sends requests downstream. The log configuration downstream uses the headers defined here, not the normal values. This solution uses but does not require `mod_unique_id` and `mod_logio`. This solution assumes that when an an `/admin/` part appears in the URL, this is for administration and should be logged. Special bad Status responses should also be logged, such as 403, 500, and 502.

In order for the Hashes to retain value across hits but be resistant to rainbow attacks, the hashes are seeded with a random value generated every time the Apache logs are rotated. This is done with RHEL's logrotate module, with an example below:

```
Define HTTPD_RND_SEED "-dummy-string-"
# Include a wildcard below for Apache < 2.4.30
IncludeOptional /var/run/httpd/random_seed.co?nf

LogFormat "%{%s}t\t%{%T}t\t%{%F}t\t%{%w}t\t%{%W}t\t%>s\t\t%a\t%u\t%v\t%{local}p\t%H\t%{SSL_PROTOCOL}x\t%m\t%U\t%q\t%{UNIQUE_ID}e\t%{Referer}i\t%{User-agent}i\t%{Cookie}i\t%f\t%D\t%B\t%O\t%{ratio}n\t%{no-gzip}e\t%{SSL_CIPHER}x\t%P\t%{tid}P\t%R\t%k\t%X\t%{ModSecAnomalyScoreIn}e\t%{ModSecAnomalyScoreOut}e" tdf_normal
LogFormat "%{%s}t\t%{%T}t\t%{%F}t\t%{%w}t\t%{%W}t\t%>s\t\t%{REMOTE_IPHASH}e\t%u\t%v\t%{local}p\t%H\t%{SSL_PROTOCOL}x\t%m\t%U\t%q\t%{UNIQUE_ID}e\t%{Referer}i\t%{User-agent}i\t%{COOKIE_HASH}e\t%f\t%D\t%B\t%O\t%{ratio}n\t%{no-gzip}e\t%{SSL_CIPHER}x\t%P\t%{tid}P\t%R\t%k\t%X\t%{ModSecAnomalyScoreIn}e\t%{ModSecAnomalyScoreOut}e" tdf_hashed

CustomLog /var/log/httpd/tdf.log    tdf_normal  "expr=-T reqenv('log_normal') ||   %{REQUEST_STATUS} in { 403,406,429,431,500,502 }"
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/tdf.log    tdf_hashed  "expr=-T reqenv('log_hashed') && ! %{REQUEST_STATUS} in { 403,406,429,431,500,502 }"

RequestHeader set "X-UNIQUE-ID" "%{UNIQUE_ID}e"

## Case 1: admin activity is fully logged, troubleshooting mode too
##         or when very bad HTTP Status, but this isn't available to if-else
<if "-f '/var/www/TROUBLESHOOTING' || %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/admin/#">
    SetEnvIfExpr "-z reqenv('nolog')" log_normal=true
    # Forward the unhashed elements downstream for its logging
    SetEnvIfExpr "%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /(.{3,})$/" X_COOKIE=$1
    RequestHeader set "X-COOKIE"             "%{X_COOKIE}e"
    RequestHeader set "X-REMOTE-ADDR"        "%{REMOTE_ADDR}s"
</if>
<else>
## Case 2: all other activity: hash IPs and cookies
    SetEnvIfExpr "true" log_hashed=true
    # Use only the last 10 characters of the hash for the IP.
    SetEnvIfExpr "md5(%{REMOTE_ADDR}.'${HTTPD_RND_SEED}') =~ /(.{10})$/" REMOTE_IPHASH=$1
    # Forward the hashed elements downstream for its logging
    RequestHeader set "X-REMOTE-ADDR"                                 "%{REMOTE_IPHASH}e"
    SetEnvIfExpr "md5(%{HTTP_COOKIE}.'${HTTPD_RND_SEED}') =~ /(.{3,})$/" COOKIE_HASH=$1
    RequestHeader set "X-COOKIE"                                      "%{COOKIE_HASH}e"
</else>
```

An example of logrotate which reseeds the hashes:

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    daily
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
         openssl passwd 20  | sed  's/^.*/Define HTTPD_RND_SEED "&"/' >/var/run/httpd/random_seed.conf
    endscript
    postrotate
        /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript

}
```